# Cron management tool design

Tags: architecture, cron, software-design

We are planning to write a web based cron management on cloud network.
It will schedule and log cron jobs on machines over the network.

We are thinking of 2 design approaches:

1. When the user schedule a job from the web interface, schedule a job on the machine using ssh and crontab command.
2. Store the job scheduling information in a database and run scripts on each machine and fetch the cron jobs meant for it.

Please suggest which approach could be better or any other better way to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

for sure store the jobs information in a database. this way you have well defined boundary of your application. you have dedicated tools to back it up, recover after failure browse state etc. most languages already have dedicated (clustered) library to manage task scheduling - just use it.

but do you really need to run some scripts on every machine? i don't know your application but maybe having separate cluster that manages job triggering is enough? or if it's more complex then maybe you need a software that does distributed processing (like map-reduce, spark or something similar)

Comment: The script for each machine I was referring to, would fetch the cron jobs from the database and schedule the jobs as cron. The reason for running it separately on each machine was that, there would be no dependency. Each would be a separate entity as far as scripts are concerned. If we use separate clusters then we would schedule the jobs using ssh on machines